# How can I get object from observable stream

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am having the following code

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient){};

ngOnInit() {
   this.$users = this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
}
```

SO after i get all users I need to filter the object where the name is `Leanne Graham`

So for that reason I add filter

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient){};

ngOnInit() {
   this.$users = this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
   const name = this.$users.pipe(filter(user => user.name === 'Leanne Graham'))
   console.log(name);
}
```

now instead of the object

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  },
```

I am getting observable. How can I get the name directly ?
Do I always need to subscribe in this situations to get the name from the stream ?

Comment: Yes, you have to subscribe to your stream. Observable is a stream, not an object.

Comment: Observables don't execute until there is a subscription, so you always had to subscribe or do something equivalent, such as `firstValueFrom`

Answer (score 0):

An observable is a stream, as with promises you need to wait for a value to be emitted. This is done with `subscribe()`.

There is no other way than `subscribe()`. Also the call to subscribe can be wrapped/hidden in particular cases. For example with the `asyncPipe` or when you convert to an promise with `firstValueFrom()` / `lastValueFrom()`.